# Hacer que una acción en un sitio tenga una reacción en otro

Tags: php, div, host

Por poner un ejemplo, tengo dos sitios web sitio1.cx y sitio2.cx, y quiero que las personas usen los dos al mismo tiempo ya que dependera uno del otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], si bien ya expusiste lo que deseas lograr, ayudaría mucho a que recibas ayuda lo que has intentado

Comment: Lee sobre websocket y Notificaciones push, luego realiza una pregunta más especifica cuando estés implementando alguna de esas tecnologías.

Comment: Gracias Cesar, eso hare

Comment: También Ajax Polling, olvidé mencionarlo como alternativa ;)